# Jdbc returning unexpexted result from database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

The code here is returning with wrong/unexpected result back from database. I dont cannot figure out the problem . Here is the code

```
import java.sql.*;

class test1
{
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");    

        System.out.println("Driver loaded successfully");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not load "+ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Connection con=null; 
    try
    {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//Apoorv-PC:1521/orcl","scott","tiger");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();  
        //st.setMaxRows(2);
        //System.out.println(st.getMaxRows());
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select park_space from park_available where area='M.P.Nagar'"); 

        while(rs.next())
        {    
            String p=rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(" "+p);
        }   
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Connection closed!");
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in database"+e.getMessage());
    }
    if(con!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Successful!");
    }
 }  
}
```

My park_available table in oracle has 5 columns: area (varchar2),arr_date(varchar2),arr_time(varchar2),**park_space(number)**,dept_time(varchar2).

here i am trying to access the 4th column "park_space" which has value "10" for each row, but my code here returns 0 when used with getInt() and null when getString() is used.

Do i have to use rs.next() method as according to my code the result returned is a particular column of a particular row i.e. only a single value?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the "CREATE TABLE ..." script? I'd like to see what types these columns have.

Comment: `getString(1)`...doesnt this return the second column, which doesn't exist in your RS?

Comment: park_space is of number datatype rest all is varchar2 type

Comment: @Zircon only 1 column and 1 row exist in rs.... and it generates " Invalid column index" error if i pass 0 or 2 or any value other than 1

Comment: What version of the JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: try rs.getString("park_space");

Comment: Calls to ResultSet#getString(int) are 1-based (first column index is 1, not 0), so Apoorv singhai's call ist correct. Furthermore, usage of rs.next() ist correct as well.

Comment: Are you definitely sure that the selected rows all have "10" as a value for the park_space column? Maybe you have inserted/updated that in an uncommitted session?

Comment: @Orin2005 still same result, no effect

Comment: @Lars Gendner  yea i am sure, i commited it and already tried it several times

Comment: @Andreas my jdbc driver version is 10.2.0.3.0

Comment: Note that `NUMBER` is a floating-point data type, so you should be calling `getDouble`. `getInt` and `getDouble` will both return `0` for null values, and `getString` of course returns null for null values, so it would seem your column has null values. Are you sure your table has value `10`? Are you sure you are connected to the right database? As the right user? Do you get the right number of rows printed? If you add an extra row, will it print one more row too?

Comment: Unrelated: You should use try-with-resources.

Comment: I bet there are more than one row that satisfies the query, one of them with the value, another one with null... and since many DB clients limit the results to a few rows, @Apoorvsinghai is not seeing this :-)

Comment: Sorry guys, my fault , i was connected to a different database that was the problem as Andreas said. Thanks to all for your responses :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(rs.next()) {    
    BigDecimal p=rs.getBigDecimal(1);
    System.out.println(" "+p);
}
```

I guess since your column is a NUMBER, it is just too big for an int (e.g. see Oracle's notes regarding data taype mappings: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/datacc.htm#JJDBC28367).

[Edit]
To import "java.math.BigDecimal" you have to add an import statement like this:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

To the beginning of your Java file.

Comment: Its generating " cannot find symbol error" do i need to import some package

Comment: BigDecimal is located in java.math. You have to add an "import java.math.BigDecimal;" to the beginning of your Java file, just below the "import java.sql.*;" line.

Comment: Ok thanks. It is working. It is working with int also just i was connected to a different database. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

To verify you don't have an issue with your driver, here is a full test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@...", "...", "...")) {
        try {
            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE NUMBER_TEST ( COL1 NUMBER )");
            }
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO NUMBER_TEST VALUES (?)")) {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    stmt.setDouble(1, rnd.nextDouble() * 100.0);
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COL1 FROM NUMBER_TEST")) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getDouble(1) + "  " + rs.getString(1));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE NUMBER_TEST");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("DROP failed: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT** (randomized data)

```
52  52.076813172962844  52.076813172962844
7  7.747368165641289  7.747368165641289
1  1.906398483271876  1.906398483271876
95  95.4035973169611  95.4035973169611
60  60.2402712112802  60.2402712112802
72  72.70235593122439  72.70235593122439
62  62.18918689642948  62.18918689642948
16  16.87108578421145  16.87108578421145
20  20.20241078545453  20.20241078545453
0  0.32630814336951364  .32630814336951364
```

As you can see, `getInt`, `getDouble`, and `getString` all return good data.

Tested on 11.2.0.4 JDBC driver against 9.2 database.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rs.next())
        {    
            String p=rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(" "+p);
        }
```

`@Apoorv singhai` You are trying to take string input whereas your column consists of Number datatype, Use this code instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dear The above your code is write no problem.

I think May be problem in Your Connection URL Check that Once clearly...

I was Executed code in Eclipse with localhost url i got output.No Errors

See Code Bellow

    import java.sql.*;

class test1
{
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");    

        System.out.println("Driver loaded successfully");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not load "+ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Connection con=null; 
    try
    {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521","sample1","sample1");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();  
        //st.setMaxRows(2);
        //System.out.println(st.getMaxRows());
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select park_space from park_available where area='M.P.Nagar'"); 

        while(rs.next())
        {    
            String p=rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(" "+p);
        }   
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Connection closed!");
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in database"+e.getMessage());
    }
    if(con!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Successful!");
    }
 }  
}
```